# Branch of multiple-valued function (complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

> Find a branch of $(z^3 - 1)^{1/3}$ which is analytic in $|z| > 1$

So we essentially want to study $\frac 13\text{Log} (1 - \frac 1{z^3} )$, the principal branch of the logarithm where $-\pi < \text{Arg} (z) < \pi $. Problems arise when $\text{Re}(z^3 - 1) \leq 0 $ and $\text{Im} (z^3 - 1) = 0$ i.e. when $z^3 - 1$ is a non-positive, real number.

Setting these equations up, how can I produce the result $|z| > 1$?

Comment: Can you find a branch of $\sqrt[3]{1-w^3}$ for $\lvert w\rvert < 1$?

Comment: I run into the same problem, having to produce that result from the real and imaginary part equations

Comment: Can you find a branch of $\sqrt[3]{1-w}$ for $\lvert w\rvert < 1$? If you do that, the solution to your problem is only a small modification away.

Comment: I would make a similar approach for that one, factoring out w and investigating the log of $1/w - 1$. But again I would have the produce that result by investigating the conditions on the real and imaginary part (respectively) of $1/w - 1$. That's where it gets hairy for me unfortunately!

Comment: That's the wrong way. You should factor out $z$ to get the above form, which you can directly solve. You don't need to consider a logarithm at all, although for $\sqrt[n]{1-w^k}$ you can, if you want.

Comment: I just realized I made a typo in my original post, fixed it now though. As you can see, I did factor out $z^3$ but was unable to proceed thereforth.

Comment: Okay, so you have factored out the $z$, good. Now, you don't need to consider the logarithm, but you can. If $\lvert z\rvert > 1$, what can you say about $\frac{1}{z^3}$? And hence about $1-\frac{1}{z^3}$?

Comment: With $|z|>1$ we can derive $\frac 1{|z^3|} < 1$ and hence $0 < 1 - \frac 1{|z^3|}$. I suspect there is some conclusion to draw here but I am not seeing it unfortunately. Here I am dealing with absolute values and I somehow want to think about the significane of this in the complex plane.

Comment: Let $w = \frac{1}{z^3}$. You know $\lvert w\rvert < 1$. So $w$ lies in the unit disk. Now, where lies $1-w$? Draw a sketch.

Comment: Hm, $1 - w$ shifts all points to the right on the plane and $-w$ just reflects the $x$ and $y$ to the opposite quadrant (diagonally). Essentially a circle around at $w = 1$ of radius 1? But the triangle inequality yields $|1 - w| = |w - 1| \leq |w| + 1 < 2$ ?

Comment: Forget about the triangle inequality. Take the unit disk. What does $w \mapsto -w$ to the unit disk [as a set, not to the individual points]? Then, what does $u \mapsto 1+u$ with that?. So, at the end, what has become of the unit circle? "Essentially a circle around at $w=1$ of radius $1$?" Drop the "essentially", it has become the circle of radius $1$ with centre $1$. Now, look at that circle (sketch it if necessary), and ponder famous domains for branches of the logarithm.

Comment: I think I get it now! The requirement $|z| > 1$ implies $|1/z^3| < 1$ i.e. complex numbers of the kind $1/z^3$ lie inside the unit disk. The operation $1 - (1/z^3)$ shifts all points to the right one unit and reflects all points diagonally (we still end up on a unit disk, but now with center at z = 1). So complex numbers of the kind $1 - (1/z^3)$ lie on the unit disk $|w-1| = 1$ and this domain is contained within the principal domain of the logarithm function and hence we can make the function in question analytic! Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes, if $w$ lies in the unit disk, then $1-w$ lies in the right half-plane. So we can without problems take logarithms or $n$-th roots there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience and guidance, much appreciated! :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Let
$$
\omega_1=1, \quad \omega_2=\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad
\omega_3=\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}.
$$

A domain for $\,\sqrt[3]{1-z^3}\,$ could be 
$$
\Omega=\mathbb C\smallsetminus \big([0,\omega_1]\cup[0,\omega_2]\cup [0,\omega_3]\big).
$$
By $[a,b]$, for $a,b\in \mathbb C$ we denote the segment connecting $a$ and $b$ in the complex plane.

Clearly $\{z:\lvert z\rvert>1\}\subset\Omega$.

In order to prove it you need the following lemma:

*If $a,b$ belong to the same connected component of $\mathbb C\smallsetminus\Omega$, then
$$
f(z)=\log\left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right),
$$
is definable as holomorphic in $\Omega$.*

Using this lemma, we can easily see that $\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3$ belong to the one and only component of $\mathbb C\smallsetminus\Omega$ and
$$
\sqrt[3]{1-z^3}=(z-\omega_3)\exp\left(
\frac{1}{3}\log\left(\frac{z-\omega_1}{z-\omega_3}\right)+
\frac{1}{3}\log\left(\frac{z-\omega_2}{z-\omega_3}\right)
\right).
$$

Comment: I am sure you have a written a neat and rigorous answer to this problem but know that for someone struggling with a rather basic concept it is *not* insightful. At all. But thank you nonetheless.